# Interact with Blockchain data

Tags: blockchain, ether, myetherwallet, explorers

I'm new to blockchain dev (not dev in general), and I'd like to interact with the blockchains, is there a general API that I can call and for example if my wallet has 3 BNB and 3 ETH I can call that API and interact with both blockchains to fetch how many coins I have? I'm looking for a decentralized solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into Web3. For Python, JS, or C#, there are the Web3.py, Web3.js, and Nethereum libraries respectively. There's a lot to explain here, so it's better you read the documentation of them or watch some tutorials.